# jQuery UI Timepicker off by 1 minute

Tags: jquery-ui-timepicker

I'm maintaining an application which uses the [jQuery UI Timepicker](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) and trying to troubleshoot a bug.

Basically, this is how to re-create it:

There are 2 timepickers, **start time** and **end time**
1. on the start-time, select 6:00am (from the *hour area*)
2. on the end-time, select 12:00pm (from the *hour area*)
3. go back to the start-time and select 00 from the *minute area*

Then some code runs to determine the elapsed time in minutes. That code is:

```
    function setDuration() {

        var $startTime = $(".field.times input[name$='StartTime']");
        var $endTime = $(".field.times input[name$='EndTime']");

        var $durationHours = $(".field.duration input[name$='DurationHours']");
        var $durationMinutes = $(".field.duration input[name$='DurationMinutes']");

        if ($startTime.val() != "" && $endTime.val() != "") {

            var startTime = $startTime.timepicker ? $startTime.timepicker('getTimeAsDate') : Date.parse('01 jan 01 ' + $startTime.val(), "hh:mm tt");
            var endTime = $endTime.timepicker ? $endTime.timepicker('getTimeAsDate') : Date.parse('01 jan 01 ' + $endTime.val(), "hh:mm tt");
            var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000 / 60;

            //check whether spanning multiple days
            if (startTime > endTime) {
                duration = duration + (60 * 24);
            }

            $durationHours.val(Math.floor(duration / 60));
            $durationMinutes.val(duration % 60);
        }
    }
```

I have found that after completing steps 1 and 2, everything is fine.
But, if I complete step 3, the *endTime* local variable is assigned a date object which has a time component of 11:59 and not 12:00.

Off by 1 minute.

If I then go to the **End Time** picker and select 00 from the *minute area*, as I did with the **Start Time** picker, the elapsed time rights itself again.

As an interesting observation when debugging, both timepickers are 1 minute behind after steps 1 and 2. That is, they are at 5:59 and 11:59. The elapsed time is correct, as the difference is important. But as a said, as soon as a user selects 00 from the *hours area*, it seems to "right itself" for that picker and the difference is out by 1 minute (until the same thing is done for the other picker).

Javascript dates are hard! Help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, figured it out. I guess it is an opinionated component which holds the opinion that the user must select a minutes figure from the *minutes area*. Because if they don't, the minutes will be -1.
Fair enough.

To fix this bug, in the onSelect handler, I wrote some code similar to this:

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
        onSelect: function (time, inst) {                 
            if (inst.minutes < 0)
                inst.minutes = 0;
        }
});
```

In our app, if they don't select '00' or any other minutes, it will be presumed to be 0.